# all works but warning show up after doing the function

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"href="includes/css/bootstrap.min.css"><?php
require_once "class.php";
$conn = new db_class();
if(ISSET($_POST['signup'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = sha1($_POST['password']);
            $confpassword = sha1($_POST['confpassword']);
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $conn->save($username, $password,$confpassword, $firstname, $lastname);



}   ?>
```

and this is the function :

```
 public function save($username, $password,$confpassword, $firstname, $lastname){
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `username` = '$username'") or die($this->conn->error);
    if($stmt->execute()){
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        if($password!=$confpassword){
            echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\"><strong>password does not match</strong></div>";
        }else
            if( $result->num_rows == 0){
                $stmt1 = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `user` (username, password, confirmPass, firstname, lastname) VALUES('$username', '$password','$confpassword', '$firstname', '$lastname')") or die($this->conn->error);

                $stmt1->bind_param("s", $username, $password, $confpassword, $firstname, $lastname);
                $stmt1->execute();
```

everything work great except this warning:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type
>   definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in C:\Program
>   Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\segments\class.php on
>   line 214

any idea? I tried to add more "s" in here:

```
$stmt1->bind_param("s", $username, $password, $confpassword, $firstname, $lastname);
```

And still have the same warning. Any ideas?

Comment: Do not use `sha1` for passwords. Use php's `password_hash`

Comment: Where is your placeholder??

Comment: You are totally confused. Your query does not need Preparing as it stands and you have no parameter placeholder so the `bind_param()` is also not required

Comment: You are using prepare statements wrong: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong

```
$stmt1 = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `user` (username, password, confirmPass, firstname, lastname) VALUES('$username', '$password','$confpassword', '$firstname', '$lastname')") or die($this->conn->error);
```

You need to have placeholders that you will bind not variables above

this is what you need:

```
$stmt1 = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `user` (username, password, confirmPass, firstname, lastname) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)") or die($this->conn->error);
$stmt1->bind_param("sssss", $username, $password, $confpassword, $firstname, $lastname);
$stmt1->execute();
```

**Update :**

this `or die($this->conn->error);` is somehow useless where you have put it as the query does not get executed, in that line you are just preparing, you need to check success/fail after `execute()`

therefore should be like :

```
<?php

$stmt1 = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `user` (username, password, confirmPass, firstname, lastname) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt1->bind_param("sssss", $username, $password, $confpassword, $firstname, $lastname);
$stmt1->execute();

if(!$stmt1){
    die($this->conn->error);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

When using prepared statements, you must use placeholders. Without them, not only would you get unecessary fatal erros, but you are defeating the use of prepared statements.

You are binding 5 variables, therefore you need 5 placeholders to bind them.

```
$stmt1 = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `user` (username, password, confirmPass, firstname, lastname) VALUES(?, ?,?, ?, ?)") or die($this->conn->error);
$stmt1->bind_param("sssss", $username, $password, $confpassword, $firstname, $lastname);
$stmt1->execute();
```